# Common Base type for WebRequest and WebClientProtocol

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, security

I'm trying to have a function that will assign the credentials property for a WebClientProtocol and a WebRequest. The problem is that, with strict option on, I can't find a base type that both inherits and exposes the 3 properties that I need:

Credentials,
PreAuthenticate,
ConnectionGroupName,

The simple sub I'm trying to make work:

```
Private Shared Sub SecureIntegrated(ByRef webRequest As ???????)

        webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        webRequest.PreAuthenticate = True
        webRequest.ConnectionGroupName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

End Sub
```

I managed with the adapter design pattern but that seems way overkill (I had to add 2 classes and one interface...). Can anyone think of a better way? I'm opened to generic but I can't think of a good way to have it working with the strict option turned on.

---

Add the following in a partial class with the same name and namespace as the service proxy:

```
public partial class Service1
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        return request;
    }
}
```

This example sets the `KeepAlive` flag, but many other things can be set.

Comment: See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/ways-to-customize-your-asmx-client-proxy/

Comment: @JohnSaunders Hey John, I can't access that link from work it seems (paranoia is law here), can you post the relevant parts of your blog post please?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Hey John, yeah I saw this method but I can't modify the proxy since I'm generating it dynamically. Is there a generic way of doing something like this?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Nevermind I could override it from the dynamic CodeCompileUnit like you suggested. Thanks a lot!